# Не работает for in с словарём

Tags: python

У меня есть словарь и две переменные. Я прохожусь по словарю и если ключ словаря == переменной **x**, то я хочу чтобы к значению этого ключа добавлялось "+1" и потом это значение записывалось в переменную **x**1.
Но у меня выскакивает эрор

```
*maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query = {'1': 5050, '102': 421, '104': 1128, '105': 11012, '112': 517, '114': 958, '115': 11012}
x = str(102)
x1 = 0
for key,value in maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query.items():
    if key == x:
        maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query[value] += 1
        x1 = value
print(maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query)*
```

вот что должно произойти с переменными после цикла:

**x** = 103

**x1** = 103

Comment: 1) Что значит "к содержимому этого ключа добавлялось "+1"? К самому ключу или к значению по этому ключу?  `   `   2) Ключи у вас строки, а `x` - число. А вы их сравниваете. `   `     3) Адресуетесь к словарю по `value` - `maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query[value]`. Хотя там явно должен быть `key`.  `  ` 4) Ну и `x1 = value` у вас никогда не получится 103. Ибо `value` - это значение по ключу, а там и близко таких чисел нет.

Comment: 102 != '102' Вы сравниваете целое число со строкой  ;)

Comment: В вопросе я имел введу к значению ключа( исправил в вопросе). Переменную тоже исправил). Действительно нужно было обращаться по ключу maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query[key] += 1, всё заработало. Спасибо большое)

Comment: -1 за то, что не читал "эрор"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

И не надо здесь никаких циклов.

```
maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query = {'1': 5050, '102': 421, '104': 1128, '105': 11012, '112': 517, '114': 958, '115': 11012}
x = '102'
x1 = 0
if x in maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query:
    maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query[x] += 1
    x1 = maxBTSID_Huawei_3G_query[x]
```